# Select values in pandas (Python) from a column that correspond with certain values in an other column

Tags: python, dataframe, row, extract, col

I have a dataframe ca_turn_real that looks like this:

```
     cosine_semanticL    condition_info
0            0.736066   dyad5-condA.txt
1             0.71984   dyad5-condA.txt
2            0.692101   dyad5-condA.txt
3            0.660092   dyad5-condA.txt
4            0.567374   dyad5-condA.txt
...               ...               ...
2330         0.557836  dyad32-condA.txt
2331         0.416025  dyad32-condA.txt
2332         0.564774  dyad32-condA.txt
2333         0.750505  dyad32-condA.txt
2334         0.582945  dyad32-condA.txt
```

I want to extract the cosine_semanticL values that correspond with a specific condition. for the cosine_semanticL's of dyad5-condA.txt . However, when I use this code:

```
print(ca_turn_real.loc[ca_turn_real['condition_info'] == 'dyad5-condA.txt'])
```

it returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [cosine_semanticL, condition_info]
Index: []
```

**What am I doing wrong here and how do I solve this?**

Comment: Hey. Your code looks correct. Maybe there is a white space before the values on the 'condition_info' columns. Could you provide an csv version of the data?

Comment: No need to send you the file. Your suggestion of the whitespace worked. Thank you!